# Is it bad practice to raise errors when input doesn't match the requirements?

Tags: error-handling, conventions

Is the following syntax acceptable, or should the raising of the error be replaced by adding the if-clause in the else statement?

Example of raising the error:

```
def ask_birth_year():
    while True:
        try:
            year = int(input('What is your birth year?'))
            if year < 1890 or year > 2023:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid birth year')
        else:
            return year
```

Alternative:

```
def ask_birth_year():
    while True:
        try:
            year = int(input('What is your birth year?'))
            if year < 1890 or year > 2023:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid birth year')
        else:
            if year < 1890 or year > 2023:
                print('Please enter a valid birth year')
            else:
                return year
```

Furthermore, which is the preferred syntax by convention?